# Use a component as the inline template for $mdDialog

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material, angularjs-components

Typically you might show a dialog with `Angular Material` like this:

```
$mdDialog.show({
    controller: FooCtrl,
    templateUrl: 'app/foo_modal.html',
    clickOutsideToClose: true
});
```

I would instead like to use a [component](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) in the inline `template` option. When I try to do that I see the screen dim, but the component's view is not visible.

It seems as though the component, `auth-modal`, is not rendered.

```
<div class="md-dialog-container ng-scope" tabindex="-1" style="top: 0px; height: 371px;">
    <div class="md-dialog-focus-trap" tabindex="0"></div>
    <md-dialog role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="dialogContent_3" aria-describedby="dialogContent_3" class="md-transition-in">
        <auth-modal></auth-modal>
    </md-dialog>
    <div class="md-dialog-focus-trap" tabindex="0"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

[Here is a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vefM9qyumYmXtObQMATG?p=preview) with a working example.

The example uses a component called `user-detail` in a dialog's inline template.

```
$mdDialog.show({
    locals: { users: su },
    controller: DialogController,
    template: '<h2>Selected users ' +
              '<button ng-click="closeDialog()">x</button></h2>' +
              '<user-detail ng-repeat="u in users" user="u">' +
              '</user-detail>',
});
```

If you are having a specific problem, please post the error message or some more info.

Comment: With your example you are still passing in a controller. It would be more ideal to create a component elsewhere, which will have its own controller, and then just render that component as the dialogue's template. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you use a `directive`, you can put the closeDialog handler in there, but `$mdDialog.show()` seems to require the controller to put the user list into the template scope, like this http://plnkr.co/edit/VjcmyDDmG9QSwv1zO5gA?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it's better to use a 'dummy template' which is your `<auth-modal>` wrapped between `<md-dialog aria-label="xyz"></md-dialog`> tags - see [this example](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/8409#issuecomment-292776251) along with the issue discussion. Then you could ditch the `<foo-modal>` (which I assume is the HTML snippet you posted) with the unnecessary `md-dialog-container` boilerplate code as `$mdDialog` service takes care of that for you.